# how to use contains in full-text index to work as like(%text%)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search

I want use **contains with full text index** and i'm looking for mean or idea to use contains instead of like(% mySerachExpr%), as you know "contains" can be used  only for searching prefix (where **contains(,'"text*"')**), i ask if there is  any idea to make optimised query using contains in order to replace **like('%text%')**.

Comment: please tag your dbms, mysql or sql-server?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  SELECT * FROM table WHERE Contains(Column, "test");
```

Comment: i 've tested it works, my question is we can't use contains with regular expression as like(%text%). **contains** searches only the prefix text*, i want suggestion to make procedure that use **contains** eventualy **like** to have somthing as  **procedure(" * text * ")**